# Data import using Power Automate and create records in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

I want to create Contact entity for this in Excel. Four fields are mentioned based those fields it should contact record and 4th field is related account entity. If the mentioned account entity record is present in CRM it should link to contact entity otherwise create account record and link entity.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it & it's too broad here.

All you have to do is parse the excel file, read the data & create the records.

1. Choose the right trigger based on your excel source file
2. Choose the Dynamics 365 connector & configure the action
3. Do a `Apply to each` iterator for excel records
4. [Refer this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/dynamics-365-lookup-in-crm-to-see-if-exists/td-p/101483) for finding a matching record & map, or create it if not available
5. Map the ready made fields for record creation

[Create Dynamics 365 Records from an Excel using Microsoft Flow](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/07/create-dynamics-365-records-from-an-excel-using-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: Thanks Arun ..Can you pls provide some starting steps to configure D 365 flow using connector and Excel sheet to used for importing contacts to create records in crm. Can you pls help on this.

Comment: @Krishna can you check the link in answer?

Comment: I am able to create records but not able to link account record to newly created contact if account exists and create account record if it doesnt exists. can you pls review screenshots which i placed in above post and suggest.

Comment: I was able to create contact records from Excel but when trying to link account record to contact record getting error .To update contact iam mapping company name with account id primary key but this is causing problem as company name is lookup field .please suggest how to map company name lookup field in update record action.